# I want to sum two different attributes based on some condition in drools

Tags: drools, rules

I want to add two different attributes using some condition in drools engine. 
Below Sample condition need to convert into drools rule,

CASE WHEN (XXX='1' OR YYY <> '#' OR
  (cast(coalesce(cast(abc as integer),0)+coalesce(cast(cdf as integer),0)as integer)>=1)
  OR aaa='1' OR abc='1' OR dfs='1'
  OR dfds='1' OR dfsde ='1' OR adbc='1' )THEN 1
  ELSE 0
  END

Comment: Show what you have done so far.

Comment: Also, share your current model.